# WebDAV files not in WebDAV repository

Tags: webdav

I have been investigating about WebDAV for a couple of weeks now and I cannot figure out how to meet my requirements.

I have to deal with a bunch of files and folders that are physically on different shared networks, on different machines and on different folders. I have to manage those with a WebDAV client. That is my requirement.

Using an IIS WebDAV server or using a third party WebDAV server is very simple because the files where physically within the server. The files are in a WebDAV repository.

My investigation leads me to think that any WebDAV client can only interact with files and folders that are physically on the server. Is that right? In other words is it possible for a WebDAV server to interact with files and folders located all over the place? If so how?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV is just a protocol that exposes files and directories. The specification says nothing about physical location, or how the ones and zeroes are stored. As long as your server 'speaks' webdav correctly, it will seem like a unified webdav server for the client.

The implication is of course, that you can't just take a standard WebDAV server and deploy it. You will need to implement your own.